# "yank" does not paste text when using Emacs over SSH

Tags: emacs, ssh, yank

When I tried to run Emacs on a remote server through ssh, the `C-y` (even `M-x yank`) can't work.
Every time I press `C-y`, it says "Mark set", but nothing else happens. I'm working under Linux and the remote server is a Mac pro.

Now I can only download the file to my pc. Any ideas on how to better solve this problem?

Comment: Not really a solution to your problem, but you could use Tramp to remotely edit the file.

Comment: (Emacs *is* a development tool and this *is* a practical problem with an objective answer; thus this question *is* on-topic here, even if it may also be on-topic on other forums.)

Answer (score 6):

I suspect your problem is not due to Emacs running remotely, but instead it is due to Emacs running in "text mode" (i.e. running inside a terminal emulator).  When running in such a mode, Emacs does not know about any surrounding GUI that might be running, so `C-y` only yanks text you have previously killed in the same Emacs session via something like `C-w` or `M-w`.

You can try to do a "paste" in your terminal emulator (probably Cmd-v), which will send the selected text to the underlying application (in this case, Emacs) as if it had been typed.  As long as the text you're pasting is made of "simple enough" characters it might work fine.  If it contains any funny control chars, all bets are off (if it contains non-ASCII chars it may also behave in a funny way, depending on whether the whole "terminal-emulator+ssh+Emacs" are configured just right or not).

Answer (score 4):

The text-mode thing wasn't my problem.

I have a macbook where I run emacs. I use tramp-mode to edit files (remotely) on a linux box. There is no remote emacs. It's all local.

I had copy/paste set like this on the mac, so I could "yank" from the system clipboard outside of emacs:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; handle copy/paste intelligently
(defun copy-from-osx ()
  "Handle copy/paste intelligently on osx."
  (let ((pbpaste (purecopy "/usr/bin/pbpaste")))
    (if (and (eq system-type 'darwin)
             (file-exists-p pbpaste))
          (shell-command-to-string pbpaste))))

(defun paste-to-osx (text &optional push)
  "Handle copy/paste intelligently on osx.
TEXT gets put into the Macosx clipboard.

The PUSH argument is ignored."
  (let* ((process-connection-type nil)
         (proc (start-process "pbcopy" "*Messages*" "pbcopy")))
    (process-send-string proc text)
    (process-send-eof proc)))

(setq interprogram-cut-function 'paste-to-osx
      interprogram-paste-function 'copy-from-osx)
```

Apparently tramp-mode tries to be smart, and when yanking text, it runs the pbpaste command that I've set up, *remotely*. Or tries to.   Which I don't want.  So I modified the `copy-from-osx` to be like this:

```
(defun copy-from-osx ()
  "Handle copy/paste intelligently on osx."
  (let ((pbpaste (purecopy "/usr/bin/pbpaste")))
    (if (and (eq system-type 'darwin)
             (file-exists-p pbpaste))
        (let ((tramp-mode nil)
              (default-directory "~"))
          (shell-command-to-string pbpaste)))))
```

Notice it sets tramp-mode to nil, temporarily, before running pbpaste.

Works for me.

Comment: Thank you very much. my configure is very similar to yours and your solution works for like a charm.

Since I defun copy-from-osx only `(when (eq system-type 'darwin)`, I removed the "if" part: `(defun copy-from-osx () (let ((tramp-mode nil) (default-directory "~")) (shell-command-to-string "pbpaste")))`